# How do you get an RSS FEED in a facebook public profile?

Tags: html, facebook, rss, user-profile

$( document ).ready(function() { $('#feed').FeedEk({ FeedUrl:'facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=12345678&format=atom10'; }); });

Comment: Can we have some more codes ? What've you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried a link with an fb page.. it works.. it doesnt work with public profile

Comment: @HikigayaEm put your code in the comment into the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Page RSS Feed has been deprecated (announced [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3)) and should not return any data since June 23rd 2015. Use the Graph API endpoint `/page-id/feed` instead